# Removing dynamic content from the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove any zero values from the end of a string. There could be no matches, or there could be several matches. Some examples:

`10d 5h 0m 0s` would become `10d 5h`

`10d 5h 10m 0s` would become `10d 5h 10m`

`10d 0h 0m 0s` would become `10d`

I toyed with the following regex:

```
(0h)?\s(0m)?\s(0s)$
```

But it only matches the first and third example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you search for the extra spaces (outside of your brackets), so it looks for <space><space>0s and will not find it, it only works if the minutes are zero You can move yours spaces into the crackets to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(\s?\b0[hms])+$/g` seems to match your spec. Start with an optional space and word boundary and match `0` followed by one of `h`, `m` or `s`, one or more times, anchored at the end of the string. Replace with the empty string.

```js
const p = /(\s?\b0[hms])+$/g;

[
  "10d 5h 0m 0s",  // => "10d 5h"
  "10d 5h 10m 0s", // => "10d 5h 10m"
  "10d 0h 0m 0s",  // => "10d"
  "0s",            // => ""
  "10d 0m 2s",     // => "10d 0m 2s"
].forEach(e => console.log(`'${e}' => '${e.replace(p, "")}'`));
```

Comment: That isn’t possible in my case.

Comment: Sure, you can toss a `d` into the bracketed group if you want that.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `split()`

```js
function removeZeros(string) {
  return string.split(/(\s|\b)0/)[0];
}

console.log(removeZeros('10d 5h 0m 0s'));
console.log(removeZeros('10d 5h 10m 0s'));
console.log(removeZeros('10d 0h 0m 0s'));
console.log(removeZeros('0s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents:

```
(\s0h)?(\s0m)?(\s0s)$
```

Comment: This does not work.  Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation.